# Simple Implementation of MATHNET Filtering Lowpass filter

Tags: c#, filtering, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I have created the following code:

```
Double[] ArrayOfData = new Double[Size] { 0.5, 1.5, ... , 1.0 };
var lowPass = MathNet.Filtering.IIR.IirCoefficients.LowPass(0, 0, 0);

MathNet.Filtering.IIR.OnlineIirFilter filter = new MathNet.Filtering.IIR.OnlineIirFilter(lowPass);

filter.ProcessSamples(ArrayOfData);
```

The problem that I am running into is that the low pass filter does not seem to do anything. I have tried different values than 0,0,0 for the lowpass but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

If anyone has some knowledge on the MathNet Filtering api, could you show a simple example or explain what I am doing incorrectly?

The nuget info can be found: http://filtering.mathdotnet.com/

It is the MathNet.Filtering - core package link that I am using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, please note that the `ProcessSamples` method returns the filtered data; `ArrayOfData` is left unmodified. You thus need to obtain the method output to be able to look at the results:

```
var processed = filter.ProcessSamples(ArrayOfData);
```

Second, the parameter combination *(0, 0, 0)* is invalid. Arguments are `samplingRate` (samples per unit), `cutoff` (cutoff frequency in samples per unit), and `width` (bandwidth in samples per unit), and as far as I know these arguments all need to be larger than zero.

Comment: It may be late but here is your check mark! Thank you.